# ext2 finding the block that contain the group descriptor from the inode number

Tags: filesystems, hard-drive, osdev, ext2

i found many source code use this method to find the group descriptor of the group that associated with  that inode number

algorithm which is as follow :

1. group number  =  inode number / how many inode per group
2. group descriptor block  = group number / number of group descriptors
   per block

the operation #2 i can't understand  .

if there is an alternative method to find the block that contain the group descriptor block ,can you explain it .